# NoMethodError in Pages#Home: Undefined method 'colour' for #<Colours:0x007fe71261c708>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Something between my home page form and the controller for it to create a database object is giving me the error in the title when I try to load the page. Not sure what's causing it, here are the relevant files/codes:

**home.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :colours do |f| %>
    <span class="form-group">
      <%= f.text_field :colour, required: true, class: "balloon", id: "colour", placeholder: "Colour category (red, blue..)" %><label for="colour">Colour</label>
    </span>
    <span class="form-group">
      <%= f.number_field :bold, required: true, class: "balloon-num", id: "bold", min: 1, max: 12, placeholder: "1-12" %><label for="bold">Boldness</label>
    </span>
    <span class="form-group">
      <%= f.number_field :bright, required: true, class: "balloon-num", id: "bright", min: 1, max: 12, placeholder: "1-12" %><label for="bright">Brightness</label>
    </span>
    <span class="form-group">
      <%= f.number_field :num, required: true, class: "balloon-num", id: "num", min: 1, max: 5, placeholder: "1-5" %><label for="num"># Colours</label>
    </span>
    <span class="form-group">
     <button class="button" id="generate" type="submit"><i class="fi-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </span>
  <% end %>
```

**controllers/colours_controller.rb**

```
class ColoursController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @colours = Colours.new
  end
  def create
    @colours = Colours.new(colours_params)
    if @colours.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Error."
    end
  end
  private
  def colours_params
    params.require(:colours).permit(:colour, :bold, :bright, :num)
  end
end
```

**controllers/pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def home
        @colours = Colours.new
    end
    private
    def colours_params
        params.require(:colours).permit(:colour, :bold, :bright, :num)
    end
end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'pages#home'
  resources :colour, only: [:home, :create]
end
```

**db/migrate/20161215012944_create_colours.rb**

```
class CreateColours < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :colours do |t|
      t.string :colour
      t.integer :bold
      t.integer :bright
      t.integer :num
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**models/colours.rb**

```
class Colours < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I've been searching and asking people what it could be all day without any luck, hopefully someone can see my error here and explain to me how to correct it. Thank you!

---

**Update** Changed ":colours" in my form_for tag to "@colours", now getting the following error:

```
undefined method `colours_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe711dbfab0>:0x007fe704401058>
Did you mean?  colours_path
```

**Update 2** In the console, 'bundle exec rails routes' returns:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern       Controller#Action
        root GET  /                 pages#home
colour_index POST /colour(.:format) colour#create
```

**Update 3** Running rails routes in console returns:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
        root GET    /                          pages#home
colour_index GET    /colour(.:format)          colour#index
             POST   /colour(.:format)          colour#create
  new_colour GET    /colour/new(.:format)      colour#new
 edit_colour GET    /colour/:id/edit(.:format) colour#edit
      colour GET    /colour/:id(.:format)      colour#show
             PATCH  /colour/:id(.:format)      colour#update
             PUT    /colour/:id(.:format)      colour#update
             DELETE /colour/:id(.:format)      colour#destroy
```

Comment: You should not have a model with a plural name. Your model should be called `Colour`, not `Colours`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is the problem:

```
<%= form_for :colours do |f| %>
```

Change it so that it uses the instance variable you defined in your home action.

```
<%= form_for @colours do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a new error now though, "undefined method `colours_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe711dbfab0>:0x007fe704401058>
Did you mean?  colours_path"

Comment: The home.html file is in your colour views or pages  views ?

Comment: Pages views, this is a one page site, do I still need to make a colours views?

Comment: When you add "resources :colours" in your routes file rails expects all the resources so be defined as methods (index, show, edit, update, delete). If you don't want to define them all you only have to specify which you want. resources :colours, only: [:home, :create] . I think this might solve your problem.

Comment: Now it's giving me the opposite error, saying "colours_path" is undefined and asking if I meant "colour_index_path". I should also mention that I unpluralized everything to "colour" instead of colours as google results lead me to believe that could solve the issue (it didn't) so I'm not sure where this "colours_path" is coming from.

Comment: type in your terminal: "bundle exec rake routes" and add that to your question. It seems like the routes are messed up.

Comment: You didn't change your routes file ? It is really odd. When you add a resource to your routes file like you did it should define all the CRUD routes but for you it only defines the index_path route. That is why you are getting the error. The router moves your request to the index_path but you don't have that index path.

Comment: It might be a little difficult to debug it right now because even if you made changes to your Models Name as you said, those changes are already saved in the database the moment you ran the command "rake db:migrate". You would have to change a lot of things. To make things easier, start a new project with "rails new ProjectName" and create a scaffold for your colours like this: "rails g scaffold Colour colour:string bold:integer bright:integer num:integer". This will generate a controller, model, views, forms, routes and migration for all your colour attributes.

Comment: Ok, remove the :home and :create and run the rake command again to see what routes rails creates for you.

Comment: Alright I did, added a lot more routes. See update 3.